# Am I able to replace the bolt in the hub to be quick release on a back wheel?

Tags: freewheel, rear-wheel, quick-release

I have [this](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-100-700-rear-free-wheel-id_8528051.html) wheel and want to replace the skewer that it is tightened with to a quick release fitting is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but it’s a bit of a project. You will need to remove the axle and transfer the hardware to a new axle that has a hole through it for the quick release skewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'bolt' through the hub is actually an axle that is threaded along its length The wheel bearings are sandwiched between 'cup' surfaces in the hub and 'cones' that thread onto the axle.

The axle in this type of hub can be replaced if they get bent or damaged, they can also be replaced with a quick release type. The quick release type has a hole though it that accepts a quick release skewer shaft.

Replacing the axle is fairly straightforward, but requires making sure you get the correct length axle and re-assembling the bearings.

Here's a [video from RJ the Bike Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsdxS046jpo) showing how to replace the axle.

Comment: You want to make sure you order an axle to fit your frame and will be shorter than the bolt on axle.

Comment: Here's a [quick release axel assembly](https://www.amazon.com/GEEDIAR-Mountain-Release-Bicycle-Skewer/dp/B01L1B80FS) that's for sale. Not a product endorsement but an example of what you'll need to replace that solid axle with a quick release set up.

Comment: wow, this is long winded, this bike is a bit of a heap of crap to be honest. My ribble got stolen in London, then when I moved to Madrid just wanted a bike so got this thinking it would be decent, should have spent extra. I have spent to much modifying it now. Think its time to invest in something better again. It's just really annoying as I always have to ride around with a 15" spanner in case I get a puncture